# How to open and play windows media player using c# console application?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am trying to write a code with which I can open windows media player and play a movie in a console application using c#.
I tried MediaPlayer class but it doesn't open the windows media player :

```
MediaPlayer player=new MediaPlayer();
Uri uri= new Uri("c:\\movies\\test.mvk");
player.open(uri);
player.play();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("wmplayer.exe", "C:\\movies\\test.mvk");
```

But I doubt Windows Media Player supports the mvk file format.

Comment: I want to get the current movie time while the movie is playing. If I use Process.Start, I won't be able to get the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
    [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd562692(v=vs.85).aspx)

secondly as mentioned by JustDevInc - `*.mvk` is not supported  by windows media player, you need `*.wma` files..

Hope this helps..