# Hyperlink for ComboBox Items LIST

Tags: c#

I have this code in VS 2022. I want to make an app to start a hyperlink I want. When I press the start button with selected item from the combobox, I want to open in another app the windows.

1. How can I put a hyperlink for `if(comboBox1.Text == "1.Test1")` ?
2. How can I introduce a media player for my app to open the link I will put it?

```
private void button1_Clsdfdsfsick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.Text == "1.Test1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("111111");
        }
        if (comboBox1.Text == "2.sdasad")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("222222");
        }
        if (comboBox1.Text == "3.sdacaca")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("333333");
        }
```

Comment: Are you after [Process.Start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32315567/how-to-open-and-play-windows-media-player-using-c-sharp-console-application)

Comment: And hiperlink for items from combobox how? :D Sorry if i am asking stupid questions. I am beginer. Sorry!